# sql perform 3 natural join then union then together

Tags: sql, syntax

I want to natural join 3 times (`Product` is inventory) then union them together but the following is not working with error `near "(": syntax error: (`, I want to see the `model` and `price` of all matching items.

```
    (SELECT model, price FROM PC) NATURAL JOIN (SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker='B')

    UNION

    (SELECT model, price FROM Laptop) NATURAL JOIN (SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker='B')

    UNION

    (SELECT model, price FROM Printer) NATURAL JOIN (SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker='B');
```

can anyone help? thanks.

Comment: What SQL technology is this?  You are saying JOIN but what are you joining on?

Answer (score 1):

What about a union of the three tables then a semijoin to the forth?:

```
WITH T AS ( SELECT model, price FROM PC 
            UNION 
            SELECT model, price FROM Laptop 
            UNION 
            SELECT model, price FROM Printer )
SELECT * 
  FROM T 
 WHERE model IN ( SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker = 'B' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be you have too many  ()  adn missing table alias

```
SELECT model, price 
FROM PC  
NATURAL JOIN ( SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker='B') t1

UNION

SELECT model, price 
FROM Laptot 
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker='B') t2

UNION

SELECT model, price 
FROM Printer 
NATURAL JOIN (SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker='B') t3;
```

if you instead of a natural join want use a inner join you can  see that the table name alais is use for identify correctly the column  related e:

```
SELECT model, price 
FROM Printer 
INNER JOIN ( 
  SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker='B'
) t3 on t3.model = printer.model ;
```

Comment: are the table  name  .. you are using a join and a join require a table name  .. so t1 , t2 . t3  are the name for the table base on your select  for join ..  and  just a question the my code in answer  work ???

Comment: so in current session, i can use that those tables like a variable?

Comment: You can use the  as the table alias for your join on for complete table.column name  .. yes (not variable  but alias)

Comment: Anyway answer updated  with a sample for inner join that refer to table alias

Comment: I mean instead of combining so many unions and joins together, can i store this 
 into `t1` and do the same for second join and third joint, in the end, i perform union on `t1`, `t2`, `t3`  like tables are stored into theses "temporary" tables

Comment: No  .. because the  table are dinamically create and not stored .. in some where  ..  .. remember that you are using an union for build a comulative table from different table  ..

Comment: thanks a lot. I am new to sql but i just want to know if there is a way to store the result of a `select` command somewhere  so i can use it later. my idea come from common programming language: like i can store `2 + 3` into a variable `i` and then later in the program, i can still use `i`, maybe do a `i*3`, instead of all put them in one line like `(2+3)*3`

Comment: You could take a look  at view  or  create temporary table  ..  there are info in doc

Answer (score 0):

you can write your query like below

```
select
model, price from (SELECT model, price FROM PC) a1 JOIN 
(SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker='B') a on a1.model=a.model 

union
 select model, price from
(SELECT model, price FROM Laptop) b1
JOIN (SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker='B') b on b1.model =b.model 
UNION
 select model, price from
(SELECT model, price FROM Printer) c1 JOIN
(SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker='B') c on c1.model=c.model
```

Comment: thanks. so this makes `natural join` into normal `join on a condition`?

Answer (score 0):

`JOIN` (and its variants) are *operators* in the `FROM` clause.  So, your queries simply do not make sense.  You are using an operator outside of the SQL clause where it makes sense.

Each query *could* be written as:

```
select model, price
from (SELECT model, price FROM PC) p NATURAL JOIN
     (SELECT model FROM Product WHERE maker ='B') b;
```

However, I consider `NATURAL JOIN` an abomination, because it matches columns by *names* rather than by explicit foreign key relationships.  This usage is slightly better than most usages. The code is explicitly selecting the columns, so the code is isolated from "unexpected" columns messing up the logic.

However, this is simpler and clearer in my opinion:

```
select p.model, p.price
from pc p join
     product pr
     on p.model = pr.mode
where pr.maker = 'B';
```

And `exists` might be even clearer:

```
select p.model, p.price
from pc p join
where exists (select 1
              from product pr
              where p.model = pr.model and pr.maker = 'B'
             );
```

Comment: "I consider NATURAL JOIN an abomination, because it matches columns by names rather than by explicit foreign key relationships" - a bit like saying, "I hate apples because they don't grow on orange trees." Again, operators in a database modification language has nothing to do with constraints in a database /by design/.